# jQuery elements added with after() have incorrect spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-after

I have a `<ul>` with a number of `<li>` elements in it. A number of them are hidden and are added to the end of the list upon clicking with jQuery `after()`.

However, for some reason, the elements added with `after()` are always a bit too close to the element they are added after.

I have made a jsbin to demonstrate [here](http://jsbin.com/licowaqe/1/)

Also, a screenshot to explain:

[image]

The reason for using `after()` instead of a simple `addClass` or `show` is because the list relies on applying styles with `li:nth-child(even)`, so if the elements are there, but only hidden, it causes issues in the styling of the list.

Comment: I don't seem to see that effect in your jsbin, all have same spacing.

Comment: @Esa Did you click? then you can see the difference.

Comment: I do see the effect, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to click the "Two" sorry. I see it now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is because the `<li>` elements are `inline`, and in your HTML are separated by a newline, which when rendered creates a space between them.

When you are programatically  inserting elements, they are not separated by a newline so no space appears between them.

You can see the effect of the newline by placing all the `li` elements on a single line, the spacing will disappear, or by adding `float:left` to the `li` in your CSS

### [Demo of this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4270/)

[More reading...](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the link for further learning about the issue, very informative and concise.

Answer (score 2):

As SW4 said. there is no spacing between the `<li>`

Here it works
http://jsbin.com/licowaqe/4/edit
the difference ist in the HTML

`data-additional=" <li>Four</li> <li>Five</li> <li>Six</li>"` has spaces

Answer (score 0):

easy fix would be - **[article](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)**

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/licowaqe/5)**

```
ul#list{      
    font-size: 0;
}

ul#list li {
    font-size: 36px; /* put the font-size back */
}
```

Comment: Although note that this doesn't work on some versions of Android, if this is a concern